# Service with AlarmManager running always every minute

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I'm trying to set a service run every 5 minutes in background. But it's acting weird:

At onCreate of Main activity, I'm scheduling it to run every 5 minute:

```
   public void scheduleAlarm(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AdSyncStartReceiver.class);
        final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, AdSyncStartReceiver.REQUEST_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        long firstMillis = System.currentTimeMillis(); // alarm is set right away
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                firstMillis,
                5 * 60 * 1000, // 5 min
                pIntent);
    }
```

AdSyncStartReceiver.java:

```
public class AdSyncStartReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  // Triggered by the Alarm periodically (starts the service to run task)
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent i = new Intent(context, AdSyncService.class);
    context.startService(i);
  }
}
```

AdSyncService.java

```
public class AdSyncService extends IntentService {
    public AdSyncService() {
       super("AdSyncService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
       // Do the task here
       Log.i("AdSyncService", "AdSyncService Service running");
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".AdManager.AdSyncStartReceiver"
    android:process=":remote" >
</receiver>

<receiver android:name=".AdManager.BootReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<service
    android:name=".AdManager.AdSyncService"
    android:exported="false" />
```

Logs, it's running every minute:

```
10-28 02:46:51.405    6820-7043/pack I/AdSyncService﹕ AdSyncService Service running
10-28 02:47:04.198    6820-7052/pack I/AdSyncService﹕ AdSyncService Service running
10-28 02:48:04.199    6820-7099/pack I/AdSyncService﹕ AdSyncService Service running
10-28 02:49:04.196    6820-7182/pack I/AdSyncService﹕ AdSyncService Service running
```

I'm trying to run every 5 minute to test but it's **always** running every minute. What's the problem?

I followed this tutorial exactly:

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Starting-Background-Services#using-with-alarmmanager-for-periodic-tasks

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me:

```
 alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 60 * 1000 * 5, pendingIntent);
```