# Write to the table every 5 minutes and always running

Tags: android, alarmmanager

**Goal:**

I want to have a service that write a record every 5 minutes in the table of database.

**The work done:**

To accomplish the goal, an `Alarmmanager` was used that did this every 5 minutes. Unfortunately, after a while the `Alarmmanager` goes off (for android 8 or above).

```
public class SensorInfoAlarmManager {
    public void setReminder(Context context) {

        MsdSQLiteOpenHelper msdOpenHelper = new MsdSQLiteOpenHelper(context);
        SQLiteDatabase dbInstanse = MsdDatabaseManager.getInstance().openDatabase();
        int interval = msdOpenHelper.getSensorInfoInterval(dbInstanse);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar setcalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        setcalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
        setcalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
        setcalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND));
        cancelReminder(context);

        ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, SensorInfoAlarmReceiver.class);
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, SensorInfoAlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        android.app.AlarmManager am = (android.app.AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.setRepeating(android.app.AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, (long) interval* 1000, (long) interval * 1000, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

It seams android does not allow the `Alarmmanager` to always be running.

I used from these solutions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33380567/service-with-alarmmanager-running-always-every-minute), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33981142/alarm-manager-trigger-every-time-app-running) and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46129451/running-an-android-service-after-every-20-sec-using-alarmmanager-doesnt-restart), but no result found.

What is the problem? Is there a better solution?

Comment: Did you check if your app is being closed by the system? Many phones close apps when they're doing to much on the background, what phone are you using?

Comment: Everything related to background and/or periodic work in Android is a mess and there are some major differences in functionality between different device manufacturers. Check out this site for more details: https://dontkillmyapp.com/

Comment: The only thing is coming in my mind right now is to use foreground service, i don't think this is the best solution, but, if you really need that alarmmanager to run continuously i think this is the way to go.

Comment: Yes Denis95 is right because Android 8.0 have put some limitations on background service and broadcast https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background

Comment: @ChagaiFriedlander I'm using a Samsung Galaxy A70 with Android Pie.

Comment: I would suggest setting the app to ignore battery optimization in the Samsung settings. Otherwise I think you might be able to get this done using Google Cloud Services.